# How would to set up interpolation functions based on parameterized tabular data for performing optimization or curve fitting

Tags: python, algorithm, interpolation, wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to set up (in Python) an optimization that involves interpolation functions.
In this example, I use Bézier functions with weights as parameters (see section for [Rational Bézier curves](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve)).
The following below is all in Mathematica, and I am trying (without any success) to do the equivalent in Python.
Below, `bezier3` is a parametric function of `t` between `0` and `1`  and returns a coordinate in the same space as `point0, point1, point2, point3`.
And so in Mathematica, I can create an interpolation function from a table of these points, such that `bezier3interpolation` is an interpolation function with some of those parameters `w1, w2, w3, p1 and p2` can be found by optimization.
(I am choosing `point0-3` such that the interpolation function to the Bézier points is single-valued.)

I'm still fairly new to Python, but I'd like to get something like what I have in Mathematica to work in Python. If you can help me do this conversion or point me in the right direction, I'd be greatly appreciative!
I have looked into `scipy.interpolate` but I'm not anywhere near competent in Python to understand how I might approach this problem, using `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` or something similar so that I can optimize these parameters governing the behavior of my `bezier3` and `bezier3interpolation` functions.

```js
bezier3[t_, w0_, w1_, w2_, w3_, p0_, p1_, p2_, 
  p3_] := ((1 - t)^3 *p0*w0 + 3*(1 - t)^2*t*p1 *w1 + 
    3*(1 - t)*t^2*p2 *w2 + t^3*p3*w3 )/((1 - t)^3 *w0 + 
    3*(1 - t)^2*t *w1 + 3*(1 - t)*t^2 *w2 + t^3*w3 )
bezier3interpolation[w0_, w1_, w2_, w3_, p0_, p1_, p2_, p3_] := 
  Interpolation[
   Table[bezier3[time, w0, w1, w2, w3, p0, p1, p2, p3], {time, 0, 1, 
     0.01}], InterpolationOrder -> 3];
point0 = {0, 0};
point1 = {30.0, 5.0};
point2 = {75.0, 7.0};
point3 = {90.0, 0.0};
data = Table[
   bezier3[time, 1.0, 10.0, 10.0, 1.0, point0, point1, point2, 
    point3], {time, 0, 1, 0.01}];
sol = FindFit[
  data, {bezier3interpolation[1.0, weight1, weight2, 
     weight3, {0, 0}, {p1x, p1y}, {p2x, p2y}, {90.0, 0}][
    x]}, {weight1, weight2, 
   weight3, {p1x, 25}, {p1y, 10}, {p2x, 70}, {p2y, 13}}, x, 
  StepMonitor :> 
   Print[weight1, " ", weight2, " ", weight3, " ", p1x, " ", p1y, " ",
     p2x, " ", p2y]]
w1fit = Part[sol, 1][[2]];
w2fit = Part[sol, 2][[2]];
w3fit = Part[sol, 3][[2]];
p1xfit = Part[sol, 4][[2]];
p1yfit = Part[sol, 5][[2]];
p2xfit = Part[sol, 6][[2]];
p2yfit = Part[sol, 7][[2]];
Show[{ListPlot[{point0, point1, point2, point3}, Joined -> True], 
  ListPlot[data], 
  Plot[bezier3interpolation[1.0, w1fit, w2fit, w3fit, 
     point0, {p1xfit, p1yfit}, {p2xfit, p2yfit}, point3][x], {x, 0, 
    90}]}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

So `Table[bezier3[time, w0, w1, w2, w3, p0, p1, p2, p3], {time, 0, 1, 0.01}]` looks something like a list of pair terms composed of the parameters, e.g.,
[image: Terms in the Table of bezier3 function. Remember that p0-3 are coordinate pairs]

The above FindFit finds the following solution, while the weights are not quite what I started with in `data`, `{p1x,p1y}` and `{p2x,p2y}` are nicely converged to `point1` and `point2`.

```js
{weight1 -> 3.55705, weight2 -> 1.26914, weight3 -> 0.0451063, 
 p1x -> 30.0092, p1y -> 5.00204, p2x -> 74.992, p2y -> 6.99736}
```

[image: Output showing the cubic Bezier function envelope (point0-3), the point data being fit to, and the Interpolation function fit to that data]
(I have no reputation to post images but the mathematica script above will generate a plot,  but https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/272635/how-would-to-set-up-python-interpolation-functions-based-on-parameterized-tabula has the same question with the figures)

EDIT: The below shows where I am stuck, with the Python structure that would look something like this, but the way curve_fit is used is quite different from the standard way in which you have arguments of the variable and parameters, xdata and ydata, but I am wondering if interp1d can still be used as part of a function definition for purposes of fitting:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

wcoeff=[1.0,10.0,10.0,1.0]
pcoeff=[(0,0),(30,5),(75,7),(90,0)]
time=np.linspace(0,1,101)
xcoeff = [0,30,75,90]
ycoeff = [0,5,7,0]

def bezier3(t,w,p):
    return ((1-t)**3*p[0]*w[0] + 3.0*(1-t)**2*t*p[1]*w[1] + 3.0*(1-t)*t**2*p[2]*w[2] + t**3*p[3]*w[3])/ \
           ((1-t)**3*w[0] + 3.0*(1-t)**2*t*w[1] + 3.0*(1-t)*t**2*w[2] + t**3*w[3])

f = interp1d(bezier3(time,[1.0,weight1,weight2,weight3],[0.0,p1x,p2x,90]),bezier3(time,[1.0,weight1,weight2,weight3],[0,p1y,p2y,0]))
xdata=bezier3(time,wcoeff,xcoeff)
ydata=bezier3(time,wcoeff,ycoeff)
popt,pcov=curve_fit(f,xdata,ydata)
print popt
```

Except those parameters in the interp1d argument I don't know what to do with those, or how to even put the parameter into that interpolation function such that the interpolation as a function argument in the curve_fit will spit out the optimized parameters

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. So what's the question?

Comment: You say you're trying, but you're not sharing any attempts - please share code that you thought would work and explain what part you are having trouble to get to work. Don't expect StackOverflow to write your code for you.

Comment: Added the python part